# How to make a JButton have a border only when active

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm making a painting tool with Java Swing. I have a panel on the right side which displays all the colors and lets the user choose between them. I'm trying to make a border appear around the button of the currently chosen color.

As it is I'm creating a permanent border around the button when I choose the color.

What I'm struggling with is making the border temporary. I mean I want it to go away when that color is no longer being used IE when the user presses another button. This is how my code looks

```
 final JButton blueKnapp = new JButton();
 blueKnapp.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
 blueKnapp.setSize(20, 30 );
 this.add(blueKnapp);

 blueKnapp.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         blueKnapp.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));

        parent.changeColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
 });
```

Comment: You need to create a list of all buttons, which can have border, and when user press one of them, you need to iterate over this list to clear borders. After that you can set the border on the last clicked button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Andrew Thompson it is bad practice to override the `paint()` method and instead should be done using the `paintComponent()` method.
Also just using the focus painting does the same job probably better.

---

What you could do is override the paintComponent-method of your button and add a check for focus of the button. If it has focus set the border to drawn, else set it to not be drawn.
Could look like this:

```
JButton blueKnapp = new JButton()
{
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBorderPainted(this.hasFocus());
    }
};

blueKnapp.addActionListener((evt) -> {
    // set the border to either black or blue randomly.
    // replace this with your "color picker color" probably.
    blueKnapp.setBorder(new LineBorder(Math.random() < 0.5 ? Color.BLACK : Color.BLUE, 3));
});
```

Comment: 1) Custom painting in an `JComponent` should be done in the `paintComponent(..)` method. 2) Already taken care of. See: [`AbstractButton.setFocusPainted(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setFocusPainted-boolean-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Didn't even think about the focus state, that's a good way to do it obviously. I will edit my answer.

Comment: `this.setBorderPainted(this.hasFocus())` seems more readable to me... "Set the border if it has the focus"

Comment: Hi guys! thanks for you answers. As it is I don't currently have a paintcomponent for my JButtion as I just set the border with        
 ` blueKnapp.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));" `. This button is in inside a class which is a custom extension of a JComponent. Could you help clarify how I could go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: Edited the answer to include these parts. Also you could also create your own class "MyJButton" extending JButton and overriding the paintComponent method this way which is maybe cleaner depending on your usage.